# How to Recognize Cover Pages in PDF-Document

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, quartz-graphics, cgpdfdocument

I would like to implement a PDF-Viewer which shows two pages of the document side by side at a time. Naturally, the document should show the cover page alone if it exists such that those pages belonging together are shown simultaneously. The problem is that some documents have a cover page as a first page and some seem to have the front cover and then the back cover as the first pages and some have neither.

My question is: How do I know if there is one or more cover pages or not? Do cover pages carry a special marking that can be recognised? Or is this maybe a matter of examining page numbers?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "cover page" notion in PDF format. You won't have this information from PDF objects. 
There is no page number information also  (besides the page sequence you already have)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 1654209. I thought that in programs like Indesign you can mark a page as cover. So this does not have an effect on the generated PDF's meta information? Do you have some kind of reference about what information is available about PDF pages?

Comment: You can found the file format spec here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html.  Indesign possibly inserts this kind of info as XMP metadata but that's no standard.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I see, there is some kind of information about the page numbers in the optional "Page Labels" described in section 8.3.1 of the reference. But indeed, there seems to be no special treatment of cover pages.